# Importing Celery in Flask Blueprints

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a Flask Application with an MVC structure:

```
my_app
├── server.py
├── requirements.txt
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
    └── model.py
├── controllers
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── client_controllers
        └──controller.py
    └── another_controller.py
└── templates
```

I use blueprints to split the server code in "controllers" so I have something like this:

#### server.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

from controllers.client_controllers.controller import controller

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'SECRET'

app.register_blueprint(controller)

# Celery Configuration
def make_celery(app):

    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = make_celery(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

#### controller.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, json, request, redirect, url_for, abort, session



controller = Blueprint('controller', __name__,
                                     template_folder='templates/')

@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b

@controller.route('/add', methods=['GET'])
def add():
    result = add_together.delay(23, 42)
    result.wait()
    return 'Processing'
```

As you may notice, celery is not imported into the controller, because I don't know how to import the celery instance from **server.py** into my **controller.py** without getting an error, I've been trying with:

```
from ...server import celery
from ..server import celery
...etc
```

but still failing with errors.

Comment: have you tried `from server import celery`

Comment: Yes, and got this error "(most likely due to a circular import)"

Comment: Hi @SebasPinto did you manage to fix this issue. I am also having a similar issue

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix this.
Followed this pattern and in celery version 4.1.x

Comment: I solved it differently, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70801192/3112724

Answer (score 13):

The flask Error `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` happens because you are not in a Flask [application_context()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/).

You should use [celery shared_task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-shared-task-decorator) which is what you need given your MVC structure.

```
celery_flask/
├── celery_tasks
│   ├── app_tasks.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── celery_worker.py
├── controllers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── some_controller.py
├── __init__.py
└── server.py
```

Script **app_tasks.py**

```
#=====================
#   app_tasks.py
#=====================
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(name='celery_tasks.add_together')
def add_together(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The [@shared_task](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/__init__.py#L28) decorator returns a proxy that always points to the active Celery instances:

```
>>> from celery import Celery, shared_task
>>> @shared_task
... def add_together(x, y):
...     return x + y
...
>>> app1 = Celery(broker='amqp://')
>>> add_together.app is app1
True
>>> app2 = Celery(broker='redis://')
>>> add_together.app is app2
True
```

After you define you task you can call them using a reference to a Celery app. This celery app could be part of the flask [application_context()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/). Example:

Script **server.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

from controllers.some_controller import controller

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.secret_key = 'SECRET'

flask_app.register_blueprint(controller)

# Celery Configuration
def make_celery( app ):
    celery = Celery('flask-celery-app', backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    include=['celery_tasks.app_tasks'])
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

def list_celery_task( ):
    from celery.task.control import inspect
    i = inspect()
    i.registered_tasks()
    from itertools import chain
    t = set(chain.from_iterable( i.registered_tasks().values() ))
    print "registered_tasks={}".format( t )
#======================================
#                MAIN
#======================================
flask_app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = make_celery(flask_app)
flask_app.celery = celery
list_celery_task( )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Script **some_controller.py**

```
#============================
#   some_controller.py
#============================
from __future__ import absolute_import
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import current_app

controller = Blueprint('controller', __name__,
                                     template_folder='templates/')

@controller.route('/add', methods=['GET'])
def add():
    print "calling add"
    result = current_app.celery.send_task('celery_tasks.add_together',args=[12,6])
    r = result.get()
    print 'Processing is {}'.format( r )
    return 'Processing is {}'.format( r )
```

Finally, start the worker to consume the tasks:

```
celery -A celery_worker worker --loglevel=DEBUG
```

Script **celery_worker.py**

```
#============================
#   celery_worker.py
#============================
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

# Celery Configuration
def make_celery():
    celery = Celery('flask-celery-app', backend='redis://localhost:6379',
                    broker='redis://localhost:6379',
                    include=['celery_tasks.app_tasks'])
    return celery

celery = make_celery()
print "tasks={}".format( celery.tasks.keys() )
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to assign celery instance to the app instance and then access it through flask's `current_app`.

In you server.py, just add:

```py
celery = make_celery(app)
app.celery = celery
```

Then you can access this in your controller.py:

```py
from flask import current_app

@current_app.celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: now i get a "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context." Tried to solve it with:
with current_app.app_context():, but same result