# Flask with Celery - Application context not available

Tags: python, flask, celery, message-queue, task-queue

I have a Flask application, which is registered as follows:

```
APP = Flask(__name__)
APP.config.from_object('config')
```

I have defined a view for a URL, in which a function is called, which interacts with the DB.

```
from tasks import some_func
.
.
.
some_func.delay(params)
```

In the tasks.py file, I am creating a Celery instance as follows:

```
# Config values don't work here
celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://', backend='amqp://')
.
.
.
@celery.task()
def some_func():
    #DB interactions
```

Now I get an error that says:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

I read about application contexts and how they can be used. I have imported `current_app` in my `tasks.py` file and tried using the context as follows:

```
@celery.task()
def some_func():
    with current_app.app_context():
        #DB interactions
```

However I still get the same error. I also tried pushing the context from the main file as follows:

```
ctx = APP.app_context()
ctx.push()
```

But no luck yet.

How do I make Celery work with Flask?

Note: I have already tried their [example here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/celery/).

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221295/python-flask-with-celery-out-of-application-context

Comment: Do you have any import of the view in the task.py? If you have one, a cyclic import can be the problem. In fact, you have DB interactions and probably the db instance uses your app.

Comment: @Nonnib I have tried that and many similar solutions, but Celery seems to be complaining still.

Comment: @Hamlett Nope. The main file imports everything to bind it together. The tasks file imports other files that do the processing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Juicy Been quite a long time since I worked on it, sorry, I don't remember if I found a solution or we changed the requirement! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Context:**
The same error happened to me while trying to send email(s) through `Celery` tasks. 
In my case, I was sending emails that was rendered by `Flask` with html templates.

**Reason:**
`Celery` and `Flask` are disconnected. Thus, Celery has no clue about application context of Flask. I had to manually inject application context.

**Solution:**
What worked for me was Flask's `app_context()` function. Simply inject/wrap application context around the function where error originate from.

**Example:**

```
from app import app
from app import mail

@celery.task
def sign_up_task(**config, **context):
    mail = Mail()
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(**config, **context)
```

Comment: Won't that create a circular import?

Comment: You can use flask "current_app"